# spring cloud FeignRibbonClient retryhandler retry configuration

Tags: spring, configuration, client, cloud, netflix

I use spring cloud and the FeignRibbonClient to access remote services. The problem is, that this client ignores the retry configuration given by the properties:

```
 example-client.ribbon.MaxAutoRetries=5
 example-client.ribbon.MaxAutoRetriesNextServer=5
 example-client.ribbon.OkToRetryOnAllOperations=true.
```

The retryHandlers are created without any configuration. What I want to get is to retry the next server after ConnectException. What I get is a RetryableException caused by a ConnectException.
Does anybody knows how to get the client call to the next server in case of a ConnectException?
Thanx
Lutz

Comment: good question..not sure why no answers though. if you figured out how, please post